# Get last tag data on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have this code:

```
var i = 0;
$('#jobs').change(function() {
  var id = $(this).select2('data')[i].id;
  var txt = $(this).select2('data')[i].text;
  $('#jobSection').append('<fieldset><legend>' + txt + '</legend><input type="text" class="form-control" name="size_' + id + '" placeholder="Size"><br/><select class="form-control" name="type_' + id + '"><option>Type</option><option value="1">Type 1</option><option value="2">Type 2</option></select></fieldset>');
  i++
});
```

With that I am appending extra input fields for each tag.

But it works only if I select tags by order otherwise it takes previous tag data.

I understand that problem is in `i` because this is not actual loop but change event.
So I want to know how to get just last tag data on change?

Full example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pegcxh74/)

Comment: Viewing the documentation, should this not be in a `select`?

Comment: I do not know jquery to write you the code. But I can point on the issue. Your data $(this).select2('data') is filled by data w/ order. It means that when you choose tags 3,4,1 - you data is actually 1,3,4. And your "i" at this moment is 2 (incremented 0->1->2 and will be 3 at the end) and you got value 4 from data, while you've clicked 1 last time. So var i is incrementing ,but you always will get the biggest tag.
UPD: Yes, this code needs redesign. As GrigTheFirst have mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var selectOption = [{
   "id": 1,
   "text": "one"
 }, {
   "id": 2,
   "text": "two"
 }, {
   "id": 3,
   "text": "three"
 }, {
   "id": 4,
   "text": "four"
 }, {
   "id": 5,
   "text": "five"
 }];
 $('#jobs').select2({
   tags: true,
   multiple: true,
   placeholder: 'Choose job...',
   data: selectOption
 });

 var selectOptionObj = {};
 $.each(selectOption, function(i, v) {
   selectOptionObj[v.id] = v;
 });

 $('#jobs').change(function() {
   var thisVal = $(this)[0].value.split(',');
   var i = thisVal[thisVal.length - 1];
   var id = selectOptionObj[i].id;
   var txt = selectOptionObj[i].text;
   $('#jobSection').append('<fieldset><legend>' + txt + '</legend><input type="text" class="form-control" name="size_' + id + '" placeholder="Size"><br/><select class="form-control" name="type_' + id + '"><option>Type</option><option value="1">Type 1</option><option value="2">Type 2</option></select></fieldset>');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<div id="jobSection">
  <input type="text" id="jobs">
</div>
```

> Refer : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3urpdsn6/1/)

Comment: Just a note regarding this solution, it works only if id's go by order from 1. If some number is missing then it fails.

Comment: Just check the updated JsFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/3urpdsn6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should redesign your application to rebuild whole #jobSelection node every time selection changed according to current selected elements. This way your #jobSelection structure always be actualized.

I looked through event object and didn't find info about last selected option. So you need to work with current state and not with changes.

If this is not the option, you can always keep previous selection state in some variable and diff it with current state on every onChange event. But I think it is not the best solution for your problem.